# Is the c-dev@axis.apache.org mailing list, um, dead?

Tags: c++, web-services, mailing-list, axis

c-dev@axis.apache.org

I've successfully subscribed to it, but nobody seems to be answering any questions there.

Comment: Do you get your own messages through the subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, no.  However, according to the archives, there has been a severe drop off that started around this time (April 2010) and it only broke 100 messages once since then (Dec 2012).  So in practical terms, kinda, yeah.

Archive stats can be seen here:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/axis-c-dev/